# Rails Routing Broken In Production - Caching of routes.rb suspected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, routes, production

Update: Turns out that this problem was because half my mongrel did not restart. Thanks all for help!

Hi folks, i have an urgent problem. Essentially, my routing works on my localhost. But when i deployed this to production, the routes does not seem to work correctly.

For example, given a new route "/invites" - sometimes i will get a 404, and sometimes it will work correctly.

I suspect there is some caching going on somewhere, but i am not sure.

**Logs: when  a page is not found (when the routes are supposed to be accurate)**

> Processing UsersController#network
>   (for 67.180.78.126 at 2010-06-01
>   09:59:31) [GET]   Parameters:
>   {"id"=>"new"}
>
> ActionController::RoutingError (No
>   route matches
>   "/comm/role_playing_games" with {}):
>   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:383:in
>   `prev_page_label'
>
>   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:238:in`
>   log_timed_info'
>   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:155:in
>   `network'
>
>   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:151:in`
>   network'
>   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:44:in
>   `turn_on_query_caching'
>
>   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:43:in`
>   turn_on_query_caching'
>   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:42:in
>   `turn_on_query_caching'
>
>   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:41:in`
>   turn_on_query_caching'
>   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:40:in
>   `turn_on_query_caching'
>
>   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:39:in`
>   turn_on_query_caching'   haml (3.0.6)
>   lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:41:in `call'
>
> Rendering
>   /mnt/app/releases/20100524233313/public/404.html
>   (404 Not Found)

Comment: Deleting and reasking a question because you didn't get an answer within an hour isn't wise.

Comment: Why did you delete your earlier question about this (2951279) only to ask it again?

Comment: Secondly, asserting that rails is at fault with caching the routes is preposterous given the stack trace you provided. There is clearly something wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the little you have posted, this definitely isn't a caching or routing problem.

It sounds like you are trying to generate a link to the previous page the person was on inside `ApplicationController` and you have a bug with it. You will have to post the relevant code from `application_controller.rb`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure you restarted your server (like apache, ngix or passenger)?
Also, sometimes a browser can cache urls, just close your browser and reopen it, see if that fixes it.

Also, once in a blue moon, I'll forget to push the code to GIT and therefore production server doesn't get the latest code. Just check that your server actually has the code there.

Comment: i did restart all my servers, but the issue is that several of my mongrels did not restart. thanks for help! =)