# No route matches only in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, routes, passenger

I'm stuck with a real strange problem.

I'm deploying my app through Passenger (with Apache). When I try my app on my computer everything is fine but when I deploy it, I have some troubles with routes... Found routes in local are not found in production.

I've seen and tried [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951894/rails-routing-broken-in-production-caching-of-routes-rb-suspected) but it's not working.

I had some troubles with assets and precompilation. I thought it was done but finally not.

If I try:

`localhost:3000/api/my_key`

`myurl/api/my_key`

I have this error on my server:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches api/8dd8ec0f20a25777775d02655f7af8ec1918b)
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:39:in `unmatched_route'
```

`routes.rb`:

```
[...]
scope constraints:  Rails.configuration.api_routing,
  defaults:     Rails.configuration.api_routing do
    namespace :api do
      ..
    end
  end
end
```

`Application.rb`:

```
config.api_routing = {host: "myurl"}
```

`ApplicationController.rb`

```
def unmatched_route
  raise ActionController::RoutingError.new("No route matches #{params[:unmatched_route]}")
end
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Can you include rake routes output for the production server?  ```RAILS_ENV=production rake routes```

Comment: Some log entries would be helpful, combined with an example of working on development and not working in production routes. Also, be sure to set your application root to /path-to-your-app/public

Comment: I've added an example. My app is running but not all routes actually. And I've notice that my url never changes. Maybe it will help. Thank you for your time.

Comment: When I check the routes on my production server I can see routes I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, it came from my DNS redirection and not from my app. This issue was linked to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26334703/failed-to-load-resource-401-unauthorized-only-with-safari).